# Selenium IDE - how to customize right click context menu

Tags: contextmenu, selenium-ide

On right click, the context menu appears and provides few selenium
commands. It does not provides all selenium commands.
The list of commands is dynamic and gets updated with mostly used
selenium commands.
I want to make the command list static for context menu.
Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to [extend the Selenium IDE](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SIDE/Writing+extensions) to add your own custom commands to the right-click context menu.

Specifically, you need to write some Javascript to add the extra commands you need to CommandBuilders.

> **Adding Command Builders**. Command Builders help users adding
>   commands to the test by showing
>   available commands in the context menu
>   when you right-click the element.

There's a number of examples on the Selenium extensions page, for example, [this one](http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/407/selected-label-command.js?version=2&modificationDate=1237947902735) is a great demonstration of how to make commands related to HTML select elements appear in the menu:

```
CommandBuilders.add('accessor', function(window) {
// Define the command that we will return
var result = { accessor: "selectedLabel", disabled: true };

// Determine if the user has clicked on a select tag
var element = this.getRecorder(window).clickedElement;
if (element && element.tagName && 'select' == element.tagName.toLowerCase()) {

    // The target is the select element
    result.target = this.getRecorder(window).clickedElementLocators;
    result.disabled = false;

    var selectedIndex = element.selectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex == -1) {
        // Handle no selection as the empty string
        result.value = '';
    }
    else {
        // Capture the inner HTML (the text shown in the select) as the value to be matched
        var selectedOption = element.options[selectedIndex];
        result.value = exactMatchPattern(selectedOption.innerHTML);
    }
}
return result;
    });
```

Once you've created your extensions, you can easily load them manually in the Selenium IDE under Options->Options, or bundle them as part of a Firefox plugin (a good tutorial for which is [here](http://reallysimplethings.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/the-selenium-ide-1-x-plugin-api-part-12-adding-locator-builders/))